# What is the algorithm for finding the shortest cycles made by the robot?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Consider a weighted directed graph, including $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, and the set $S \subseteq V$. A robot will make some shortest cycles, namely $c_j$, in this graph. Each node in the set $s_i \in S$ has a frequency, namely $f_i$, which is the number of times the node $s_i$ has been visited by the robot *during all the shortest cycles* made by the robot(not necessarily one cycle). Note that the cycle must start and end from node $w$ ($w$ does not belong to $G$). So, the inputs are $V, E, S, w$ and the set $\{(s_1, f_1), (s_2, f_2), ..., (s_i, f_i)\}$, where $f_i$ is the node's frequency.

In the following, we discuss the details.

- The robot makes shortest cycles ($c_j$) that pass through one or more nodes in the set $S$ *at least once*. The robot will not pass through the nodes in the set $(V-S)$ at all.
- Note that the robot could make a similar shortest cycle several times, which is called the cycle's frequency, denoted as $g$. This means that after returning to the starting node $w$, the robot could make the same cycle several times, which is $g$.
- After the robot has made all the shortest cycles, **all** the nodes in the set $s_i \in S$ must have been visited.
- Remark: I emphasize that every made shortest cycle could include one, two, three, ..., or all nodes in $S$, but at the end (after making all the shortest cycles), all the nodes in $S$ must have been visited.

Now I am looking for an algorithm that outputs the shortest cycles, i.e., $c_j$ made by the robot and the corresponding cycles' *frequency*, namely $g_j$. By a cycle's *frequency*, I mean the number of times a shortest cycle is made by the robot. The output format, e.g., could be like $\{(c_1, g_1), (c_2, g_2), ..., (c_j, g_j)\}$.

A solution to this problem is valid if the number of times a node in the set $s_i \in S$ visited during making all the shortest cycles by the robot is equal to $f_i$, i.e., the node $s_i$'s frequency, which is given in the question as the input. For example, if the node $s_1$ is visited 5 times by the robot ($f_1 = 5$), then the output $\{(c_1, g_1 = 2),(c_2, g_2 = 3)\}$ is considered valid given that $s_1$ is located in both the cycles. This is because the node $s_1$ is visited twice in cycle $c_1$ and visited three times in cycle $c_2$, which is visited five times (in total), which is matched with $f_1 = 5$ in the input.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: How does the robot move? Does it start at $w$, then choose a shortest cycle covered by $S$, then move along the entire cycle until it reaches $w$ again, then choose the next shortest cycle and continue as before? Or some more complicated movements? And what is the input to your algorithm? Only the node frequencies?

Comment: @Matja: You are right. It starts at w and moves through some nodes in S, and returns W(by making the shortest cycle), and then again starts at w, passes through some nodes in S, and moves back to w.  Note that at the end, the robot must have visited all nodes in S. The input to the algorithm is the graph, including all nodes and edges, S, and the frequencies.
I emphasize that in each cycle, there could be two, three, ..., or all nodes in S, but at the end (after making all cycles), all the nodes in S must have been visited.

Comment: If the robot is taking the *shortest* cycle at each step, then it doesn't have the flexibility to satisfy the other conditions, except by coincidence.

Comment: @Misha: I mean that if the robot selects three nodes in S to pass through, it makes the shortest cycle passing through the three nodes.

Comment: @AmirHoseinAdavoudi So it's not that the cycle you find is forbidden from passing through the nodes in $V-S$. It's that the nodes in $V-S$ that it passes through are irrelevant; once you pick the nodes in $S$ you're going to use, you then select the shortest cycle that visits those nodes in $S$, plus any nodes it wants outside $S$. Do I have it right?

Comment: @Misha: The robot cannot use the nodes in V - S. In fact, we can create the induced subgraph, including the vertices in S, and every path in the original graph that only uses vertices from S can be found in the induced subgraph, too. The robot can just move in the induced subgraph.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4616867/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/157040/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Please also see the feedback there about how to improve the question and [edit] your question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W.: I edited my question. Sorry for the typos

Comment: @D.W.:I think this question would be better moved to cs.stackExchange.com as it seems more relevant to computer science, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @AmirHoseinAdavoudi, I would recommend that you start by revising the question to address all the feedback that has been provided, so that it is clear what is being asked.

Comment: I can't tell whether $f_i$ is an input to the algorithm or an output.  The phrasing in the question suggests that $f_i$ is calculated based upon the cycles chosen, which are an output from the algorithm, which would mean that $f_i$ is another output.  I don't see a specification of what the output is.  I assume the output is a list of cycles.  Now, what is the full set of conditions for a proposed output to be considered correct?  The second bullet item is not a description of what is acceptable, it seems like it is trying to propose an algorithm.  Is $w$ an input or an output?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for any algorithm, regardless of its running time.  Are you sure that is what you want to ask for?  I suspect that an answer to that will not be useful to you.  Do you have a running time bound (e.g., you want a polynomial time algorithm)?  What is the most efficient / best algorithm you have been able to find so far?

Comment: D.W.: As far as I know, my problem is related to the TSP problem, which is an NP-hard problem, and I don't think that there will be a polynomial time algorithm for it.

Comment: D.W., I already made my question clearer based on your very helpful feedback.

Comment: D.W., I should mention that I replaced a cycle's frequency denoted as $F_j$ by the notation $g_j$ (as it is now) to avoid confusion.